# Alguém sabe como mudar essa configuração do VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quando eu digito no vscode fica aparecendo três pontinhos em cima do código e sumindo. Parece algo bobo mas está me incomodando a tela ficar descendo e subindo, porque eu acabo clicando errado. Já tentei ver alguma configuração sobre salvamento automaticamente e não é, ou algo que atualize quando eu digito, mas entrei num beco sem saída.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No meu caso eu apenas desinstalei a extensão Git Lens do VS Code e desabilitei o salvamento automatico.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).